# How to use fonts which are not present in client system to build web site?

Tags: fonts

I was trying to create my portfolio website and wanted to use some fonts like "Myriad Pro" and  "Gotham" (Source : [http://www.inspirationbit.com/16-best-loved-font-bits-in-web-design](http://www.inspirationbit.com/16-best-loved-font-bits-in-web-design/)/) .But i dont think those fonts will be in the client machine for the browser to support it.I am wondering how can i use these stylish fonts in my website ? Any workaround ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check out [the Google Webfont API](http://code.google.com/webfonts). Since "Myriad Pro" and "Gotham" are not in the standard Google Font Directory, you'll also have to take a look at [the Webfont Loader](http://code.google.com/intl/nl-NL/apis/webfonts/docs/webfont_loader.html).

Another option if this won't work is [sIFR](http://wiki.novemberborn.net/sifr/), a text replacement technique.

Using [CSS3](http://www.css3.info/preview/web-fonts-with-font-face/) is also an option, although it may not be supported in older browsers.

Comment: Another pro with Google Web Fonts it is that it runs from Google's servers from all over the world. These servers are totally smart ass computers, figuring out where in the world a computer is when it loads a page with Google Web Fonts in it, and there by providing the fonts from the most near by (or most accessible rather) server. This will vastly improve load times if your site is visited by people from all over the world, compared to having the fonts load from one server that maybe happens to be on the wrong side of the planet.

Answer (score 1):

Google has a beta project called the [Google Font API](http://code.google.com/apis/webfonts/), which lets you include fonts that won't necessarily be present in the client machine.  But it doesn't have a long list of supported fonts yet.

There's also a company called [TypeKit](http://typekit.com/) that has a paid service to do something similar, with a larger set of fonts available.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Cufon](http://cufon.shoqolate.com/generate/) for this purpose.

Cufon basically converts the words into image kind format on the pageload with the fonts that you want to use.

Answer (score 0):

[FontSquirrel](http://www.fontsquirrel.com/) gives you some packages that can help. You can even upload your own font and download that as a package. Works on most browsers too :)

Don't forget to buy the font though, most are copyrighted.